# Visio 2013 configuration issue

Tags: microsoft-visio, microsoft-visio-2013

How can I make the configure box in Visio 2013 appear? I tried manually and generating a new calendar, no luck. Creating the new calendar should make the box pop up and manually clicking the menu item should also do it. Neither or these have worked for me.

I'm using Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

You should start by creating a new diagram
ribbon **New** -> **Schedule** -> **Calendar**

That should open the **Calendar Shapes** stencil and add and entry **Calendar** to the ribbon.

If that doesn't happen then there is a Visio setup problem (which can be dealt with if that is the case).